# Why does this holding pattern have both minimum and maximum altitudes published?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, instrument-approaches

**Reference the VOR-A Approach to Stellar Airpark (P19), in Chandler, Arizona (shown below):**

When JAROD INT is used for missed approach holding the published procedure calls for the aircraft to climb to **3900** feet.  The terminal transition from STANFIELD [TFD]  to JAROD is a NoPT route at 3900 feet (no holding/course reversal [unless approved by ATC]), and the terminal transition from PHOENIX [PXR] to JAROD is 4700 feet.

Why then is it necessary to **publish** a hold altitude of (Maximum) **6000** feet and (Minimum) **3900** feet at JAROD when anything other than **3900** feet (missed approach altitude) or 4700 feet ( would seemingly have to be assigned by ATC?

For perspective, I have annotated the position of **JAROD** and **Stellar** **Airpark** (P19) on the Phoenix Terminal Area Chart (IWA R-220, PXR R-150, TFD R-355) shown on the second image below.
[image]

[image]

Comment: To my understanding, NoPT does **not** mean that the hold can not be used as an actual hold.

Comment: @DeanF. - If you want to make a turn in holding on a NoPT route you must get approval from ATC.  Also, the base of the Class B airspace as the hold is started is 6000 feet.  So if you are at 6000 feet you are in the Class B airspace.  Note the location above identifying "JAROD INT"

Answer (score 3):

So that it keeps you under the shelf of the adjoining bravo airspace and because the decent gradient may be steep enough to require an upper limit. [As discussed here](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/acf/media/RDs/15-02-297_Charting_HILPT_Max_Holding_ALT.pdf):

> The instrument approach procedure Holding Pattern In Lieu Of Procedure
> Turn (HILPT) is designed to facilitate alignment with the final
> approach course. The descent gradient from the **HILPT altitude to the
> Final Approach Fix (FAF) altitude is limited by TERPS criteria to
> permit aircraft deceleration and configuration for the final approach.
> Due to a combination of this descent gradient requirement and the
> surrounding terrain, it may be necessary to employ a smaller than
> desired holding pattern template to define the HILPT protected
> airspace. Use of this smaller template may require the designation of
> a maximum holding altitude on the 8260-2 Form.** This becomes the
> maximum altitude the aircraft is permitted to enter the HILPT unless
> ATC can ensure obstacle clearance by keeping the aircraft at or the
> minimum vectoring altitude (MVA) or the minimum

[image]
([source](http://vfrmap.com/))
(red circle is roughly where the hold is, arrow points to minimum altitude)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Dave’s answer...

Just because this hold pattern is used as a Missed Approach holding pattern and as a waypoint when joining the procedure from the IAF VORTAC, it does not mean the hold could not be used for other purposes.

An aircraft could fly to JAROD as an Initial Approach Fix from any direction and use the hold to descend down to 3900 feet MSL. To avoid the Class B airspace, the upper limit of the hold is capped. This gives the non-participating VFR pilot the necessary clearance needed to use the pilot-controlled airport even when not in communication with anyone.

Comment: If you want to make a turn in holding on a NoPT route you must get approval from ATC. Also, the base of the Class B airspace as the hold is started is 6000 feet. So if you are at 6000 feet you are in the Class B airspace. Note the location above identifying "JAROD INT"